# Предварительный просмотр ссылок на странице

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

В общем-то необходимо реализовать предварительный просмотр веб-страниц, при вставке ссылки в сообщение чата, как во многих других сервисах (Skype, Telegram, Вконтакте, Facebook и т.д.). Чтобы вылазил небольшой блок и отображалась миниатюрная версия сайта (не живая, обычная картинка), а сам блок был ссылкой какую указал пользователь. Как это вообще можно реализовать? А то в интернете почти ничего об этом нету.

Comment: По моему это довольно сложная функция и она реализована на сервере. У клиента просто картинка готовая появляется.

Comment: Для таких задач использутся микроразметка [opengraph] (http://ruogp.me) от Facebook и [Schema] (http://schema.org/) от Google, Microsoft, Yahoo и Яндекс. Вам необходимо ее парсить с сайта с которого вы хотите получить превью.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin Понял, спасибо. А есть ли варианты реализовать это без парсинга? Что-то вроде сделать скриншот сайта с помощью сервера и отобразить его на сайте.

Comment: Для таких целей можно использовать selenium например. Вот простая [статья (англ.)](https://medium.com/@ronnyml/website-screenshot-generator-with-python-593d6ddb56cb). Но лично я не считаю это решение целесообразным. Скриншот будет актуальным на данный момент, но что произойдет если сайт изменится? Создавать новый скриншот? Оставлять старый? Но тогда в чем смысл. К тому же создавать скриншот для каждого запроса очень затратно при высокой нагрузке. Тогда вам стоит подумать о кешировании.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin Да, как оказалось непростая задача. Спасибо, за помощь.